# Puppeteer Page content after click on link in iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, puppeteer

I load a page with iframe in it and click on a link in the iframe like this:

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
await frame.click('a');
await page.waitFor(5000);
```

Everything works fine, puppeteer navigates to the new page.
Now I want to click on en element in the new page.
But I don't find the content of the new page.

```
const content = await page.content();
```

Gives the original page.

```
const content = await frame.content();
```

Gives the original content of the iframe in the original page.

How can I refer to the newly loaded page?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

The iframe link opened in a new tab.
Therefore I had to select it first like this:

```
const pages = await browser.pages()
const newPage = pages[pages.length - 1];
await newPage.bringToFront()
const content = await newPage.content();
```